# A function having poles at a sequence that has a limit point

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

This question was asked in my complex analysis end term exam which I got from senior and I was unable to solve it.

> If f(z) has poles at  sequence of points ${z_n}$ and ${z_n} \to {z_0}$ , then prove that f(z) doesn't have pole at $z =z_0$.

I don't have any intuition on which result should I use.

It's my humble request to you to kindly tell on how should I approach it's proof.

Thanks!!

Comment: $z_0$ is a pole of order $k$ means that $(z-z_0)^k f(z)$ is analytic around $z_0$, thus $f(z)$ is analytic on $0<|z-z_0|<r$ for some $r>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False statement in case $z_n=z_0$ for all $n$. True if this case is excluded.

A pole is an **isolated singularity**. This means if $f$ has pole at $z_0$ it must be analytic throughout some disk containing $z_0$ except for the point $z_0$. So the conclusion follows just by **definition**!.